# Access private files with extra parameters AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I have quite a few PDF files which are stored as private on an AWS S3 storage.
I'm creating a url to access the pdf through python boto library (with signature and signed headers) and successfully able to access the files if I just provide the PDF file name. But I need to access these PDF files at a particular page and with some additional parameters (bold highlighted). e.g:

https://mybucket.amazonaws.com/media/private/xyz.pdf**#page=6&zoom=100&toolbar=0&navpanes=0**&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=***********************&X-Amz-Date=20180925T044257Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a9ba6473464trdfghf76c578475hdfjdbv792cf7f1193fe8a274549

When I try to access the file with additional params, it gives me 'Resource not found" error but without the params, it accessible.

Can anyone guide me to achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

The issue was that we need to append the PDF arguments after the signature in the url.
In my case it was:

https://mybucket.amazonaws.com/media/private/xyz.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=***********************&X-Amz-Date=20180925T044257Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a9ba6473464trdfghf76c578475hdfjdbv792cf7f1193fe8a274549#**page=6&zoom=100&toolbar=0&navpanes=0**